# Sql query order by 3 countries and then by name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to order my data in this way:

1) get those rows with `Country=Belgium;`

2) get those rows with `Country=United Kingdom`;

3) get those rows with `Country=France`;

4) get all other rows in alphabetical order.

Currently I order them alphabetically:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Name) table";
    if (isset($_POST['search'])){

    $search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
    $sql .="WHERE Name LIKE '%{$search_term}%' ";
    $sql .=" OR Mission LIKE '%{$search_term}%'";
```

How can I bring those rows with Belgium, UK and France in front?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by
  case Country -- or is it Name ?
     when 'Belgium' then 0
     when 'United Kingdom' then 1
     when 'France' then 2
     else 3
  end,
  Name
```